# Is it feasible to visit these location with a day trip from Copenhagen?

Tags: denmark, day-trips

I am planning to go to Copenhagen for about 7-10 day later this year. Apart from visiting the city, I am considering doing some day-trips with public transportation (i.e., no car).

In particular I am interested in castles and old cities, so I was considering Malmö, Helsingør, and maybe Odense.

Is it possible to reach and visit these destination within a day-trip with public transportation from Copenhagen?

Comment: If you at all like art, consider coupling Helsingør with a trip to the [Louisiana Museum of Modern Art](https://en.louisiana.dk/), which is beautiful. It's along the same train line, so if you start early enough in the morning, you can start at the museum, then proceed on to Helsingør.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. I work in Copenhagen and have colleagues living in (and commuting from) both Odense, Helsingør and Malmø. Odense is (by far) the furthest away, and that is only 1½ hour by train (in the worst case).